# Azure Private End Point - not connecting from Azure Function

Tags: azure, private

I have an Azure SQL Database with a private end point setup and my Azure function can connect to it in one environment. Public Access is set to Deny for the SQL instance.

I have another function in another vnet that doesn't connect to the SQL instance. The function is on a vnet with Route All enabled. How can I diagnose this?

I have tried using the Console using the following commands:

tcpping `FQDN:1433`

^ the above works and says it can connect.

nameresolver `FQDN`

^ the above resolves to a public IP address.

SET WEBSITE_DNS_

^ returns 168.63.129.16

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to missing DNS entries in the second environments vnet DNS Server section.